# Mysql case if result found in first case do not run next

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables where I need to return matching results on basis of CASE statement.
If the query returns data in the first case. We need to return data. We do not need to check the following case statements.

This is what I tried

```
Select
    CASE 
        WHEN foo.Marks ='Two' AND t1.Subject = 3 THEN foo.UniqueValue
    END as 'Result',
    CASE 
        WHEN foo.Marks ='0' AND t1.Subject = 3 THEN foo.UniqueValue
    END as 'Result1',
    CASE 
        WHEN foo.Marks IS NULL AND t1.Subject IS NULL THEN foo.UniqueValue
    END as 'Result2'
    from (
select t1.Marks, t1.Subject, t1.Student, foo.UniqueValue from `table1` t1
inner join `table2` t2 on t1.Student = t2.GroupName
where t2.GroupID = 2
)foo;
```

| id | Marks | Subject | Student | UniqueValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Two | 3 | FOO | AIR1 |
| 2 | 0 | 3 | FOO | AIR2 |
| 3 | NULL | NULL | FOO | AIR3 |

| id | GroupID | GroupName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | FOO |
| 2 | 3 | BAR |
| 3 | 7 | FOO123 |

Level 1 -> If `Marks` and `Subject` matched it should return that `AIR1`.

Level 2 -> If `Marks` is `0` and `Subject` is `3` should return `AIR2`.

If both above cases do not find any result then the below case should be checked.

Level 3 -> If `Marks` is `NULL` and `Subject` is `NULL` should return `AIR3`

If in Level1, the matching row is found it should return that Level2,3 should not be checked.

In the final, I should only get a single row matching the above levels by priority.

Comment: Why do you need the join condition ? Could you post expected result for your data ?

Comment: Need to find groupName matching groupID

Comment: Are you looking for something like: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8863cb91952c8b8dacbcfeb39481c344

Comment: Yes something like this. But Like you see we are getting 3 rows. If first case is matched row. It should not check second level. It should return only one result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `GroupID` is known,

```
SELECT t1.UniqueValue
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.Student = t2.GroupName
WHERE t2.GroupID = 2
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN t1.Marks = 'Two' AND t1.Subject = 3 THEN 1
    WHEN t1.Marks = '0' AND t1.Subject = 3 THEN 2
    WHEN t1.Marks IS NULL AND t1.Subject IS NULL THEN 3
    ELSE 4 END ASC
LIMIT 1
```

To get one result for each `GroupID`

```
WITH cte AS (
 SELECT t1.UniqueValue, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t2.GroupID ORDER BY CASE WHEN t1.Marks = 'Two' AND t1.Subject = 3 THEN 1
    WHEN t1.Marks = '0' AND t1.Subject = 3 THEN 2
    WHEN t1.Marks IS NULL AND t1.Subject IS NULL THEN 3
    ELSE 4 END ASC) rn
 FROM table1 t1
 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.Student = t2.GroupName
)
SELECT UniqueValue
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do ELSE instead of END and new CASE?

```
Select
    (CASE 
        WHEN foo.Marks ='Two' AND t1.Subject = 3 THEN foo.UniqueValue
    ELSE
        WHEN foo.Marks ='0' AND t1.Subject = 3 THEN foo.UniqueValue
   ELSE
        WHEN foo.Marks IS NULL AND t1.Subject IS NULL THEN foo.UniqueValue
    END) Result
    from (
select t1.Marks, t1.Subject, t1.Student, foo.UniqueValue from `table1` t1
inner join `table2` t2 on t1.Student = t2.GroupName
where t2.GroupID = 2
)foo;
```

Comment: Tried that too not working.